# Как через cmd глобально запускать python скрипты

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cmd, flask

Например при создании проекта `Django` надо использовать команду `django-admin startproject 'имя проекта'` ,где `django-admin` - это `python` файл.
То есть мы не зависимо от местоположения запускаем файл `django-admin`.
Я использовал shebang, а также в переменную окружения `PATHEXT` добавил `.PY`.
Проблема в том что не получается запускать скрипт глобально.

Например если я нахожусь в диске `C:\`,а скрипт находится в `C:\Users\Siyovush\Desktop` и во время запуска скрипта пишет, что

```
"имя_скрипта"
не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Но когда я нахожусь в том же `C:\Users\Siyovush\Desktop` то получается запускать питоновский скрипт не используя слово `python`.

Как сделать чтобы я смог без ошибок находясь в `C:\` запустить скрипт находящийся в `C:\Users\Siyovush\Desktop` или в любом-другом месте.

Comment: Интерпретатор должен быть в `PATH`.

Comment: Да.Интерпретатор также есть в Path.Когда я нахожусь в той же папке где и скрипт она запускается но в других местах нет.

Comment: Хех, так там привязка к определенному пути походу. Динамически получать путь к текущей папке можно в самом запускаемом файле - dir_path = of.path.dirname(__file__), а потом все пути - images_path = os.path.join(dir_path,'images') - к примеру.

Comment: Все, у меня получилось запустить скрипт глобально.Причина была в Shebang.Сначала Shebang был таким: #!/usr/bin/env python.Но потом я изменил это на :#!c:\users\siyovush\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe. Потому что это было в скрипте django-admin в папке Scripts а не в папке django.

Comment: Также этот скрипт надо добавить в папку Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете прописать полный путь к файлу ( включая сам файл )

Например:

C:\Users\ВАШЕ ИМЯ\Django_Project\ll_venv\Scripts\Activate